# how to Check if a XML child element exists with Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

How can I check if `IncomingConfig` element exists by use linq to xml?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
  <IncomingConfig>
    <ip>10.100.101.18</ip>
    <port>5060</port>
  </IncomingConfig>
  <Device>
    <username>tarek</username>
    <AgentName>tarek</AgentName>
    <password>ffff</password>
  </Device>
  <Device>
    <username>adf</username>
    <AgentName>adf</AgentName>
    <password>fadsf</password>
  </Device>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
bool b = xdocument.Descendants("IncomingConfig").Any();
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you only want to check if `IncomingConfig` is a child of the root note (and not a descendant of any other node), use `xdocument.Root.Element("IncomingConfig") != null`.

Comment: @L.B my bad..I had mistaken the namespace as an element

Comment: Correction - "Element" should be plural .. so xdocument.Root.Elements("IncomingConfig") != null. Thanks !